# How to click a specific row in tablewidget using a function in Pyqt?

Tags: python, qt4, pyqt

In my program, function add_host runs when the program launches and at the same time I want the first row of the table to be clicked. How to do that, any idea?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your `QTableWidget` as `tw`, you simply need to call

```
tw.cellClicked.emit(row, column)
```

or

```
tw.itemClicked.emit(tw.item(row, column))
```

In your case where you want the first row to be clicked you would probably have `row = 0` and `column = 0`.